# Get array length of a multiple fields of a node content type

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm developing a site with Drupal 8. I made a custom content type, with a lot of fields; in particular I have a field called `field_categoria_del_libro_presen` that is linked to a taxonomy term. It's possible to specify more than one value. I used `kint()` to obtain the structure of the node. Here:

```
field_categoria_del_libro_presen
→array(2) target_id
  1
    "1"
  2
    "4"
```

how can I get the length of the array?

Comment: Have you tried simply `count`ing it?

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed that as suggested in the comments, the following works quite well:

```
count($node->field_categoria_del_libro_presen);
```

Here the count would be `2` (based on the example in the question).

This works because even though the `field_categoria_del_libro_presen` property on the node object is a `EntityReferenceFieldItemList`, it implements (by way of implementing [`ListInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21ListInterface.php/interface/ListInterface/8)) the native [PHP `\Countable` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php).